# How do I find where the environment variables are defined in Linux

Tags: bash, variables, hadoop, environment

I just started learning hadoop (CentOS7), here is a question about environment variable:

In my VM, rxie is the logged on user:
HADOOP_CONF_DIR = /opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/rxie

There is no path of /opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/rxie
it should be /opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop

I am trying to find out where the variable is defined so that I can correct it.
here is what I come up:

```
bash-4.2# grep -r HADOOP_CONF_DIR ~/.*
/root/./.bashrc:export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

Please note HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop is correct.

I don't see where the erroneous HADOOP_CONF_DIR is defined?

It would be appreciated if anyone can enlighten me and offer a fix, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic "" 7>trace.out
```

When that completes, run:

```
grep HADOOP_CONF_DIR trace.out
```

The output will show you every time that `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` was set, the file that set it, and the line number in that file.

#### Example

Let's take as an example something that I have in my `.bashrc` file:

```
$ grep HISTFILESIZE trace.out
++ /home/john1024/.bashrc:193:export HISTFILESIZE=20000
```

This shows that is was line 193 of `~/.bashrc` that set `HISTFILESIZE`.

#### How it works

This command starts a `bash` login shell with diagnostics turned on.  The `PS4` variable sets the prefix for the diagnostic output so that it contains the file name and line number.  For more details, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/591723/221266).

#### Other method

Although it is less reliable, one can also try:

```
grep HADOOP_CONF_DIR ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/profile /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you, I got this output when running the first command:
    bash-4.2# PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic "" 7>trace.out
    /bin/sh: BASH_XTRACEFD: 7: invalid value for trace file descriptor
Sorry I am new to both Hadoop and Linux, can you post a screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: That's curious.  Let's try a different file descriptor number like `PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=4 bash -xlic "" 4>trace.out`.  The output from this command, if any, depends entirely on your personal initialization files.  It may show no output at all; you would just see another prompt, at which point you can run the `grep` command.

Comment: Thank you, here is the output:
     bash-4.2# PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=4 bash -xlic "" 4>trace.out
    /bin/sh: BASH_XTRACEFD: 4: invalid value for trace file descriptor.

btw: should the script be executed directly? I mean, look at my output, it is right after the su prompt: bash-4.2#

Comment: _"should the script be executed directly?"_  What do you mean by that?  How have you been executing it?

Comment: Also, the error messages indicate, strangely, that 4 or 7 are not valid file descriptors.  Is there more that I should know about your operating environment?  Also, if this method continues to give you trouble, please see updated answer for another method.